# Follow up on "allowed" languages on Korean.SE

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-all-questions-be-in-english-apart-from-the-example), we had a discussion of which languages would be allowed on Korean.SE.

The discussion mainly revolved around whether we should allow questions to be asked in Korean as well as in English. As a mod, I will let all good questions written in Korean be asked. One thing that I would ask is that we avoid asking questions in Korean just to practice our Korean. This is sort of a soft rule, but make sure that you seek to use proper grammar and spelling (Don't tell me you are a 회개사 if you actually are a 회계사. Did you eat 게고기 or 개고기? etc.).

Overall, I have the philosophy that one should use the language one is better at. For me, that is English. For others of you, that might be Korean.

**However**, please avoid asking, answering, or commenting in languages other than Korean or English *if possible*. We are sort of assuming that if you are using this site, you know one of these languages well enough to ask, answer and comment in Korean or English. Do not ask a question in German just because you can. Write in Korean or English. Is this assumption too harsh?

**More However,** I will myself avoid immediately deleting things written in say Chinese, Japanese, etc. I will most likely comment and ask that someone translate these comments/questions/answers into English or Korean. If no one does in a few days, I might delete the comment, question or answer. This is done to avoid unknowingly perpetuating spam questions.

There are of course exceptions. [This answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/is-there-any-chance-that-a-korean-language-learner-uses-%E3%85%82%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4-ever/1811#1811) is an example. Since the Japanese was relatively easy to infer from (and moreover the OP seemed to know Japanese), I will let things like this stand as is. Even I myself use hanja in my answers. (In other words, use hanja freely. But consider writing the 한글 pronunciation).

For reference, my thoughts come in part from [this meta question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/may-i-ask-a-question-in-language-est-ce-que-je-peux-poser-une-question-dans) on the French Language site (and including the links to German.SE).

Let me know of your thoughts on these ground rules.

Comment: Hi Vladhagen. The question to which you referred was quite actively responded to - do you think there is a big difference between your thoughts here and the higher-voted answers there?

Comment: The previous question was a discussion on if Korean was okay to use as a means of asking and answering. I have already dealt with removing spam comments and questions fully in Chinese. My post here is more to present what I, a mod, see as being my approach to these situations.

Comment: I think what you've said is quite nicely in line with the most popular answers in that linked question, which (IIRC) is our best guide to what the community consensus is currently.

Comment: Okay. That's fair. I agree that the previous discussion is our best guide.

Comment: You should learn how SE works before you think you are a moderator on any site. I undeleted my answer. Read it again. All right?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your feedback. I will be certain to take your suggestions into account.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, I don't understand the purpose of this meta post. Especially,

> As a mod, I will **let** all good questions written in Korean be asked.
>   One thing that I would ask is that we avoid asking questions in Korean
>   just to practice our Korean. This is sort of a **soft rule**, but **make
>   sure that you seek to use proper grammar and spelling** (Don't tell me
>   you are a 회개사 if you actually are a 회계사. Did you eat 게고기 or 개고기?
>   etc.).

These sentences demonstrate you don't have enough experience on Stack Exchange, not to mention as a moderator. (I am sorry, but I need to be a little blunt and straightforward.) As a moderator or any non-mod member, you should edit the question which uses '회개사' in place of '회계사'. That's why we have a free, low-barrier editing service and that's how you contribute to this community. People do make mistakes and it sounds like you won't allow any misspelled Korean words.

Secondly, You need to note that you are not the boss here. You are just a member with a little more power. But as I mentioned in the earlier post, this community has been well managed without any moderator. **You don't let anything. Our community lets or prohibits anything based on our consensus.** You just monitor if what we have agreed (our consensus) is being implemented properly. How about broken English that is broadly used here? Can you stop it?

> Do not ask a question in German just because you can. Write in Korean
>   or English. Is this assumption too harsh?

Based on my experience on other language sites, no user would ask a question in other languages than English and Korean here. Even if a new user uses other languages in their question, as you mentioned, I think we can deal with the situation.

> My post here is more to present what I, a mod, see as being my
>   approach to these situations.

I agree with @topomorto's comment. We have already agreed to use English and Korean here. But, if other languages can add more clarity and examples, why not? For example, if the OP had included "医者になってください" in the question, [Why use 가 in 의사가 되세요?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/why-use-%EA%B0%80-in-%EC%9D%98%EC%82%AC%EA%B0%80-%EB%90%98%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94), none of the two answerers who answered before my answer would have been confused. The question was unclear from the beginning and it got only clearer when the OP posted the Japanese sentence in the comment.

I am more worried about posting an answer when a question is not clear than any OP using other languages in their question or comment. The key factor should be "Does using another language help to make a question more helpful and clear?" **If yes, why not?**

Please focus your attention on getting consensus from users rather than expressing your positions or opinions on a certain issue.

> There are of course exceptions. [This answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/is-there-any-chance-that-a-korean-language-learner-uses-%E3%85%82%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4-ever/1811#1811) is an example. Since the
>   Japanese was relatively easy to infer from (and moreover the OP seemed
>   to know Japanese), I will **let** things like this stand as is.

Again, you don't let anything stand as is. If you find any issue in any post or comment, **please discuss this issue with other two moderators or seek opinions from other users here detailing your specific concern.** That's what Meta is for.